# Java Math Functions for BigDecimal

Tags: java, math, bigdecimal

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Java BigDecimal trigonometric methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2173512/java-bigdecimal-trigonometric-methods)

Are there complementary mathematical functions used in `java.lang.Math` that fully utilize the capabilities of `BigDecimal`? In other words, is there a log function that takes and returns a `BigDecimal` similar to how there is a log function that takes and returns a `double`?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/739532/logarithm-of-a-bigdecimal .

Comment: specifically just the log function? if so then this is a duplicate per Zed's answer. otherwise which function(s) do you need?

Comment: Other elementary functions such as exponential, cos, atan, etc.