# Scala math lib for BigDecimals

Tags: scala

Is there any scala math like library which uses `BigDecimal`'s instead of doubles. I want to use such functions as sin, cos etc. But I want to pass and return BigDecimals from them

Comment: Since you can call Java libraries from Scala, I'd take a look at this question: [Java BigDecimal trigonometric methods](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2173512/java-bigdecimal-trigonometric-methods)

Comment: https://github.com/non/spire ?

Answer (score 1):

The big-math library is written in Java, so it should be usable from Scala as well.
It provides all the standard advanced mathematical functions (pow, sqrt, log, sin, ...) for BigDecimal.

https://github.com/eobermuhlner/big-math