# Arbitrary pre-set precision decimals (Almost like BigDecimal)

Tags: java, performance

I'm looking to have a java class that will hold a decimal value with an arbitrary pre-set precision.  The class `BigDecimal` looks to be a good candidate as a starting point, but I want to able to limit the size of the decimal to whatever an end user decides. Literally speaking, the end user would specify a range in base 10 and I would allocate enough bytes to represent any number in that range.

I was thinking of having a class that extends `BigDecimal`.  In this class I would add the functions necessary to mimic a decimal within a pre-set range.

My questions to the community are:
Are there any libraries that already do this?
Would extending `BigDecimal` be a reasonable thing to do?

Comment: Specify a range? maximum value? maximum absolute value? number of decimal digits? number of decimal places? NB the 'are there any libraries' part of this question is off-topic.

Comment: Note that BigDecimal already has a scale value which, when positive, essentially limits the number of digits to the right of the decimal point. You can also supply [MathContext](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/MathContext.html) to maintain this scale.

Comment: So, what difference do you need from the existing behavior? If it is performance, as the tags suggest, what order is the expected length of the decimals - tens? thousands? And more importantly, have you benchmarked BigDecimal in your use case and confirmed that the bottleneck is exactly in how they deal with scale?

Comment: I need Performance and a fixed byte size in advanced.  The length of decimals can be any order of magnitude.  It maybe be small if you just want accurate money representation.  This class will represent an option for an end user who wishes to sacrifice performance for accuracy on a case by case basis.  The fixed, arbitrary, byte size is critical though, more than performance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest you an intermediate way in between the proposals you made:

The `Apfloat` library is a good way to try with, check out the [API docs](http://www.apfloat.org/apfloat_java/).
`Apcomplex` is a wrapper class for e.g. a `BigDecimal`.

So here you would have a big freedom on overriding and enhancing new methods just applying this class.

Answer (score 1):

Interestingly BigDecimal has everything you need already. The simple methods add(BigDecimal), multiply(BigDecimal), etc.. work with unlimited precision.

The methods add(BigDecimal,MathContext), multiply(BigDecimal,MathContext), etc.. allow specifying a requested upperbound on the number of digits the resulting mantissa should have.

So basically you get results back in the form:

```
sign * mantissa * 10^exponent
```

With the guarantee that `0=< mantissa < 10^requested`. The methods do a rounding according to the [mode](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/RoundingMode.html) specified in the MathContext.