# Any way to store extremely precise numbers in java?

Tags: java, precision

I am looking for a way of storing really precise and also really large numbers in java. I want something like a double, but ideally with a few hundred bytes instead of only 8. I would like to be able to evaluate trig functions and things more complicated than basic arithmetic with this level of accuracy.

This isn't that important, but I would like to know if this is possible.

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html

Comment: **Yes**. [`BigDecimal`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html).

Comment: [`BigInteger`](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/java/1514/biginteger#t=201703232203535355597) for big integers. [`BigDecimal`](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/java/1667/bigdecimal#t=201703232204255361422) for arbitrarily precise floating point numbers.

Comment: BigDecimal is your best friend :). The only limit now is your RAM.

Comment: There's no built-in support for trig functions with `BigDecimal`, though.

Comment: See Question: [Java BigDecimal trigonometric methods](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2173512/642706)

Answer (score -2):

You can use [`BigInteger`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html) or [`BigDecimal`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html). I recomend use `BigInteger` just because in Java 8 it has been made a mayor improvements in that class.

Regards

Comment: How would you store _something like a double_ as BigInteger?

Comment: I need decimals, bigInteger can hold large enough values, but big decimal is still limited since it can't change the number of significant figures. One problem is also that java's sin() and cos() and pow(), etc, functions aren't nearly precise enough. I know a way I could do this with a lot of difficulty, but I guess what I'm really wondering is if someone has made a library to do this.

Comment: @OusmaneMahyDiaw Since when do Comments trump Answers on Stack Overflow? Please cite documentation for this major policy change.