# trigonometric math with BigDecimal useless?

Tags: java, bigdecimal

- Is there a loss in precision when using `BigDecimal` multiplied by `sin`, `cos`, `tan` or any other trigonometric methods?
- Is it valid to use `BigDecimal` with rational numbers?
- I know, `BigDecimal` is used for "precision currency calculations" ([Java BigDecimal trigonometric methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2173512/java-bigdecimal-trigonometric-methods)). I know, there are projects like https://github.com/eobermuhlner/big-math or http://www.apfloat.org/. Where lies the difference when using double for that without `BigDecimal`? Because having `BigDecimal` and converting to *double* only because I need the `exp` of it, does this makes sense. Precision is lost when using trigonometric methods. Or not?

**The question is: Does it even make sense to use `BigDecimal` with "rational numbers"?**

Comment: I am sure you are aware that storing any real number in memory is inherently imprecise to an extent. What level of imprecision are you detecting? How precise do you need your calculations?

Comment: Actually, I am using; MathContext MATH_CONTEXT = new MathContext(40, RoundingMode.HALF_UP); and want to hold that precision. Do I need these kind of external libs or does java takes care of these when using its trigonometric methods?

Comment: "storing any real number in memory is inherently imprecise to an extent"..what is the extent? Does it relate to the processor?

Comment: It's nothing to do with the processor. How would you store pi in any data structure you like? How would you store 1/3 as a BigDecimal? Obviously, using a specified precision.

Comment: So when I want to retain "new MathContext(40, RoundingMode.HALF_UP);" with trigonometric methods. How should I do this. I must convert to double to use these kind of maths. Hence, original precision is lost. Or?

Comment: You'll have to write your own trig functions from scratch using methods such as BigDecimal.add and BigDecimal.multiply. Just like how the standard Java.lang.Math trig functions have been implemented. But be aware that your BigDecimal trig functions will be much, much slower than the java.lang.Math methods.

Comment: Thanks. Now its clear: So JDK does not provide "precision settings" for trig functions. This is the reason for libs such as ApFloat or BigMath.

Answer (score 1):

**JDK does not provide "precision settings" for trigonometric math methods (sin, cos, log, exp, etc.).**

This is the reason for libs such as "ApFloat" or "BigMath".