# How To Code this formula in Java?

Tags: java, math, logarithm

I have tried to represent this formula in Java but the values are not correct maybe I have some issue transforming the formula to code.

[image: formula]

```
private double getFactor(int y) {
    double factor = 10 * Math.pow(3, logOfBase(2, 10 + Math.pow(y, 3)));
    return factor;
}

public double logOfBase(int base, double num) {
    return Math.log(num) / Math.log(base);
}
```

Comment: The base of a log is at the bottom, no? This is log_10 to the power 3. Either way, your code is not the same as the formula as `Math.pow(3, ...)` means 3 to the power something, which appears nowhere in the formula.

Comment: What _is_ the formula you are trying to code?

Comment: What is your expected result? And what should `y` equal to attain this answer?

Comment: Not sure, but this might be related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1497400/why-log1000-log10-isnt-the-same-as-log101000?rq=1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about splitting it into more parts:

```
double temp = (double)10 + Math.pow(0, 3); // 0 = y
double factor = 10 * Math.pow(Math.log(temp), 3); //Math.log - Returns the natural logarithm (base e) of a double value

System.out.println(String.valueOf(factor));
```

op:

> 122.08071553760861

Comment: Thanks this solution works fine the final code `double factor = 10 * Math.pow(Math.log(10 + Math.pow(time, 3)), 3);`

Comment: You are welcome. Maybe its just my personal opinion but i like to split functions into more parts, when they become more complex :)

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for log base 3, not log to the power of 3. Therefore, the formula should be

```
double factor = 10 * logOfBase(3, 10 + Math.pow(y, 3)));
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I have tried in base 3 but the result is wrong

Comment: What is your expected result?

Comment: For y = 0  ~~ 122.081

Answer (score 1):

To go on Ben Win's for all values of y.

```
public double getfactor(int y){
double temp = (double)10 + Math.pow(y, 3); //
double factor = 10 * Math.pow(Math.log(temp), 3); 
return factor;
}
```