# Math.log() is giving me wrong values with c#

Tags: c#

I'm having problems using `Math.log` in C#, it's giving me wrong values.

In my code:

```
Math.log(0.137931034482758)
```

returns: `-1.98100146886658`

but with a calculator

```
log(0.137931034482758)
```

gives `-0.86033800657099`

Why is that?

Comment: You should learn mathematics before. `Math.log` returns the neperian logarithm (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x80ywz41(v=vs.110).aspx) while `log` on your calculator returns the decimal logarithm, they're the same except for a factor.

Comment: I suspect you're using log base 10 on the calculator, whereas `Math.Log` returns log base e.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There seems to a bit of confusion between log(n) and ln(n) where log(n) is really log<sub>10</sub>(n) and ln(n) is the natural logarithm and is equivalent to log<sub>e</sub>(n) and

So, mathematically

```
log(0.137931034482758) = -0.86033800657099565123053753815789
```

but

```
ln(0.137931034482758) = -1.9810014688665879083488077894557
```

Looks like Math.Log uses the natural logarithm.

If you want log<sub>10</sub>(n) then use `Math.Log10(n)` or `Math.Log(n, 10)` instead.

#### UPDATE

As pointed out by @Nae these aren't necessarily equivalent though!

| Operation | Result |
| --- | --- |
| `Math.Log10(1000)` | 3 |
| `Math.Log(1000, 10)` | 2.9999999999999996 |

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1497500/592958) to [Why log(1000)/log(10) isn't the same as log10(1000)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1497400/why-log1000-log10-isnt-the-same-as-log101000) may explain why

Comment: Keep in mind that `Math.Log10(1000) == Math.Log(1000, 10)` is [`False`](https://repl.it/@baliibrahim/LogDifference)

Comment: Also see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1497400/7032856) perhaps.

Answer (score 0):

As Daisy sais:

`log(-1.98100146886658)` with basis `e` is `-1.98100146886658`

`log(-1.98100146886658)` with basis `10` is `-0.86033800657099`

Math.log uses per default e as a basis https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/x80ywz41(v=vs.110).aspx

And your calculator obviously uses uses basis 10.