# How to do a fractional power on BigDecimal in Java?

Tags: java, formula, bigdecimal, pow

In my little project, I need to do something like `Math.pow(7777.66, 5555.44)` only with VERY big numbers. I came across a few solutions:

- Use `double` - but the numbers are too big
- Use `BigDecimal.pow` but no support for fractional
- Use the `X^(A+B)=X^A*X^B` formula (`B` is the remainder of the second num), but again no support for big `X` or big `A` because I still convert to double
- Use some kind of Taylor series algorithm or something like that - I'm not very good at math so this one is my last option if I don't find any solutions (some libraries or formula for `(A+B)^(C+D)`).

Does anyone know of a library or an easy solution? I figured that many people deal with the same problem...

p.s.
I found some library called ApFloat that claims to do it approximately, but the results I got were so approximate that even `8^2` gave me `60`...

Comment: Could you give an example of what you try to accomplish, 8^2 != 64 sounds poor and 2^100^100 needs to be scaled down.

Comment: I must say I tried the formula trick, and it works fine so far even with numbers with millions of digits! (Looks like I don't know everything about double and int)...
Examples:
50!^10! = 12.50911317862076252364259*10^233996181
50!^0.06 = 7395.788659356498101260513
The code is a little long to post here, but you get the idea of X^(A+B)=X^A*X^B...
Now I'm trying to understand how and why (and if) it really works with numbers that huge.

Comment: I have already given the solution there 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11848887/bigdecimal-to-the-power-of-bigdecimal-on-java-android/22556217#22556217

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The solution for arguments under 1.7976931348623157E308 (Double.MAX_VALUE) but supporting results with MILLIONS of digits:

Since double supports numbers up to MAX_VALUE (for example, 100! in double looks like this: 9.332621544394415E157), there is no problem to use BigDecimal.doubleValue(). But you shouldn't just do Math.pow(double, double) because if the result is bigger than MAX_VALUE you will just get infinity. SO: use the formula X^(A+B)=X^A*X^B to separate the calculation to TWO powers, the big, using BigDecimal.pow, and the small (remainder of the 2nd argument), using Math.pow, then multiply. X will be copied to DOUBLE - make sure it's not bigger than MAX_VALUE, A will be INT (maximum 2147483647 but the BigDecimal.pow doesn't support integers more than a billion anyway), and B will be double, always less than 1. This way you can do the following (ignore my private constants etc):

```
    int signOf2 = n2.signum();
    try {
        // Perform X^(A+B)=X^A*X^B (B = remainder)
        double dn1 = n1.doubleValue();
        // Compare the same row of digits according to context
        if (!CalculatorUtils.isEqual(n1, dn1))
            throw new Exception(); // Cannot convert n1 to double
        n2 = n2.multiply(new BigDecimal(signOf2)); // n2 is now positive
        BigDecimal remainderOf2 = n2.remainder(BigDecimal.ONE);
        BigDecimal n2IntPart = n2.subtract(remainderOf2);
        // Calculate big part of the power using context -
        // bigger range and performance but lower accuracy
        BigDecimal intPow = n1.pow(n2IntPart.intValueExact(),
                CalculatorConstants.DEFAULT_CONTEXT);
        BigDecimal doublePow =
            new BigDecimal(Math.pow(dn1, remainderOf2.doubleValue()));
        result = intPow.multiply(doublePow);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        if (e instanceof CalculatorException)
            throw (CalculatorException) e;
        throw new CalculatorException(
            CalculatorConstants.Errors.UNSUPPORTED_NUMBER_ +
                "power!");
    }
    // Fix negative power
    if (signOf2 == -1)
        result = BigDecimal.ONE.divide(result, CalculatorConstants.BIG_SCALE,
                RoundingMode.HALF_UP);
```

Results examples:

```
50!^10! = 12.50911317862076252364259*10^233996181

50!^0.06 = 7395.788659356498101260513
```

Comment: This is not useful without the `CalculatorUtils`, `CalculatorConstants`, or `CalculatorException` classes

Answer (score 2):

The [big-math](https://github.com/eobermuhlner/big-math#bigdecimalmath) library released under MIT license has a simple static helper `BigDecimalMath.log(BigDecimal, MathContext)` for log and many other functions not included with BigDecimal. Very simple to use and has lots of benchmarking data to compare performance.

Answer (score 0):

Exponents = logarithms.

Take a look at [Logarithm of a BigDecimal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/739532/logarithm-of-a-bigdecimal)

Comment: The source code referred to the accepted answer of this question has more solutions than just for natural log.

Comment: @Prunge - Thanks.  I never actually said anything about natural log.  Really, if you look at the Gene Marin's accepted answer, what he is describing is logarithmic.   X^(A+B)=X^A*X^B is equivalent to saying log(base X)A + log(base X)B = log(base X)(A*B).  This should allow you to bring the numbers to a manageable order of magnitude .