# how to use a double value in power function

Tags: android

i am trying to find the power of a value.But the problem is my exponent is a fractional value.power function does not suppporting any datatype other than int.

```
 BigDecimal fd_returns_at_time_of_replace=(BigDecimal.valueOf(capitalDiff).multiply((BigDecimal.valueOf((long)constant1+.09)).pow(temp)));
```

here temp is a fractional value.given below is the eror message i am getting.

```
The method pow(int) in the type BigDecimal is not applicable for the arguments (double)
```

please anybody help me to do this.

Comment: then pass `int` type as argument or type cast `double` to `int`.

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3579779/how-to-do-a-fractional-power-on-bigdecimal-in-java

Comment: no..i want to use the same value.i mean i need that fractional value.i cant round or typecast the value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`BigDecimal.pow()` only takes an `int`.  To see a cool example of writing BigDecimal.pow() that accepts a double, see this question [How to do a fractional power on BigDecimal in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3579779/how-to-do-a-fractional-power-on-bigdecimal-in-java)

Comment: i read that answer.but i could not understand anything.i am not that familiar with android.can you please simplfy that.

Answer (score 1):

***Common Sense***

Consider you want to raise the number *x* to the power *y*

If both are integers:

```
for(int i=0 ; i<y ; i++)
    answer = answer * x;
```

Problems are only when *y* is a decimal!

So we first change *y* to the form of *y = n + 1/d*

How to do that:

- *n = floor of y*
- *d = 1 / (y - n)* << integer

Now *x^y = x^n* * *x^1/d*

- *x* to the power *n* is simple using the usual method
- *x* to the power *1/d* is simply the *d* th root of *x*

---

Note: You can increase the precision of your function by reducing the error factor induced by makind *d* an integer. How! *1/d* can be multiplied by powers of 10.