# How to calculate power with no integer bigdecimal expoent?

Tags: java, bigdecimal

Trying to calculate (a+b)^n where n is a real value in a BigDecimal variable, but BigDecimal.pow is designed for accept only integer values.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Logarithm of a BigDecimal](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/739532/logarithm-of-a-bigdecimal)

Comment: If the exponent doesn't fit into an Integer, the result will be _very_ big.

Comment: @JanDvorak How about `2.1234`?

Comment: @assylias admitted. I was thinking about `2^100` but `2.1234` is not an integer either.

Comment: It probably will be next to 1, but can be 0.84 or 1.59 for example.

Comment: @PeterLawrey Let's assume he calculated `logValue = n * log_base(a+b)` he still needs to calculate `base ^ logValue`...

Comment: then you have the `scaleByPowerOfTen` method, which also takes an integer...

Comment: You could use the Taylor polynomial, but that kinda sucks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [BigDecimal to the power of BigDecimal on Java/Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11848887/bigdecimal-to-the-power-of-bigdecimal-on-java-android)

Comment: @ArthurJulião The obvious solution is to convert (a+b) and n to double, use Math.pow, and convert the result back to BigDecimal. That has two limitations: It can only handle numbers in the double range of magnitudes, and you only get about 15 significant digits. Which of those applies to your problem?

Comment: It truly solve my problem @PatriciaShanahan, I just didn't realize that.

Comment: I've entered it as an answer just so that the question will drop off the unanswered list.

Comment: @ArthurJulião If you only need 15 digits of accuracy, why are you using BigDecimal?

Comment: @PeterLawrey, the infrastructure is using that, I recive the values in BigDecimal and need to convert to BigDecimal to show it after.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the input is within the magnitude range supported by double, and you do not need more than 15 significant digits in the result, convert (a+b) and n to double, use Math.pow, and convert the result back to BigDecimal.

Answer (score 1):

As long as you are just using an integer for the exponent, you can use a simple loop to calculate x^y:

```
public static BigDecimal pow(BigDecimal x, BigInteger y) {
    if(y.compareTo(BigInteger.ZERO)==0) return BigDecimal.valueOf(1); //If the exponent is 0 then return 1 because x^0=1
    BigDecimal out = x;
    BigInteger i = BigInteger.valueOf(1);
    while(i.compareTo(y.abs())<0) {                                   //for(BigDecimal i = 1; i<y.abs(); i++) but in BigDecimal form
        out = out.multiply(x);
        i = i.add(BigInteger.ONE);
    }
    if(y.compareTo(BigInteger.ZERO)>0) {
        return out;
    } else if(y.compareTo(BigInteger.ZERO))<0) {
        return BigDecimal.ONE.divide(out, MathContext.DECIMAL128);    //Just so that it doesn't throw an error of non-terminating decimal expansion (ie. 1.333333333...)
    } else return null;                                               //In case something goes wrong
}
```

or for a BigDecimal x and y:

```
public static BigDecimal powD(BigDecimal x, BigDecimal y) {
    return pow(x, y.toBigInteger());
}
```

Hope this helps!