# Java's BigDecimal.power(BigDecimal exponent): Is there a Java library that does it?

Tags: java

Java's `BigDecimal.pow(int)` method only accepts an integer parameter, no `BigDecimal` parameter.

Is there a library, like Apache's commons-lang, that supports `BigDecimal.pow(BigDecimal)`? It should be able to do calculate `"1.21".pow("0.5")` to return `"1.1"`.

Comment: Looked at the source? http://javasourcecode.org/html/open-source/jdk/jdk-6u23/java.math/BigDecimal.java.html probably not too difficult to implement your own.

Comment: Maybe this source code (http://stackoverflow.com/a/3590314/592228) can be of help? You wouldn't need any other library.

Comment: I have already given the solution there 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11848887/bigdecimal-to-the-power-of-bigdecimal-on-java-android/22556217#22556217

Comment: For those as me who searched for it : https://github.com/eobermuhlner/big-math

Comment: I didn't want to use a third party library so these solutions didn't work for me. I just converted the BigDecimal to double, did pow with double, and converted it back after.: return value.toDouble().pow(other.toDouble()).toBigDecimal()

Answer (score 41, accepted):

There is a [Math.BigDecimal implementation of core mathematical functions](http://arxiv.org/abs/0908.3030v3) with source code available from the Cornell University Library [here](http://arxiv.org/src/0908.3030v3/anc) (also you can download the library as a [tar.gz](http://arxiv.org/src/0908.3030v3)). Here is a sample of the library use:

```
import org.nevec.rjm.*;
import java.math.BigDecimal;

public class test {
    public static void main(String... args) {
        BigDecimal a = new BigDecimal("1.21");
        BigDecimal b = new BigDecimal("0.5");

        System.out.println(BigDecimalMath.pow(a, b).toString());
    }
}
```

Prints out:

```
1.1
```

---

## Update

The license information is now clear in the May 2015 update:

> The full source code is made available under the LGPL v3.0.

Comment: Interesting. What's the license of this code? Is it open source? BSD, MIT or ASL licensed?

Comment: How can I add this library as an external jar file? I don't see any jar file.

Comment: @the_prole Download the [tar.gz](http://arxiv.org/src/0908.3030v2) file, extract the content and then locate the `anc` folder, `cd` into it, then execute `make BigDecimalMath.jar`, this should build the `BigDecimalMath.jar` file that you can use as an external library

Comment: @higuaro Thanks, i made a new package in eclipse, closed eclipse, copied and pasted the .java files into the package, and re-opened eclipse. Worked fine for me. I don't know how to execute a make file.

Comment: @higuaro Any idea why I get this result? BigDecimalMath.pow(3,3)=1E+1

Comment: I have the same problem as @the_prole it's rounding way too much...

Comment: You can use check if the power is an integer using something like `x == Math.ceil(x)` and then using the standard `BigDecimal.pow(int)` which should be more precise for the particular case

Comment: I would recommend not using this. Using JUnitQuickcheck for verifying that `x^1` is the identity function yielded `4^1=3`, with this library.

Comment: This function does not support negative bases

Comment: @the_prole (and others) The `BigDecimal`s you pass in need to have a sufficiently high precision: pow(3.00, 3.00) returns 27. But it seems if you put in `BigDecimal`s of precision p you get back a result of precision p-1 (pow(3.000, 3.000) returns 27.0; pow(3.0, 3.0) returns 30 (3E+1)).

Comment: @higuaro how do I extract my tar.gz file using Windows? I can't extract it, even with  WinZip.

Comment: Hey @NoobyProgrammer. For Windows, perhaps you could try the 7zip UI, here's a link: https://www.7-zip.org/download.html 
It supports a wide range of compression related formats.

Comment: @higuaro   what is the 'cd' folder mean?

Comment: @NoobyProgrammer probably in your context `cd` means `current directory`. On the command line, `cd` refers to the program that changes the current directory, more info here: https://www.digitalcitizen.life/command-prompt-how-use-basic-commands

Comment: @higuaro thanks I've already implemented it into my programs

Comment: I tried this library but ended up using https://github.com/eobermuhlner/big-math instead which I can really recommend. The library suggested in this answer was much slower and threw exceptions more often. Also, in the library suggested in this comment, all functions take a `MathContext` as well, analoguously to the functions in `BigDecimal` which the library suggested in this answer does not.

Answer (score 7):

Havent used, but saw [suanshu](https://nm.dev).
An open source version in github (https://github.com/nmdev2020/SuanShu).

BigDecimalUtils has a pow() which suits your needs

```
public static java.math.BigDecimal pow(java.math.BigDecimal a,
                                       java.math.BigDecimal b)
Compute a to the power of b.
```

Comment: SuanShu is a good answer, unfortunately it has a commercial license (not compatible with my apache licensed work) and it is not available on maven central (not compatible with distribution method).

Comment: Looks like it has since been made open source under Apache 2.0 license. See https://github.com/aaiyer/SuanShu

Answer (score 5):

The Apfloat library seems to be doing this, check the [API docs](http://www.apfloat.org/apfloat_java/docs/org/apfloat/ApcomplexMath.html#pow%28org.apfloat.Apcomplex,%20org.apfloat.Apcomplex%29).

```
ApcomplexMath.pow(Apcomplex z, Apcomplex w)
```

Apcomplex is a wrapper class for e.g. a BigDecimal.

Comment: LGPL and in Maven: nice. Only have to figure out to convert `BigDecimal` to and from `Apcomplex`

Comment: According to the javadoc `new Apcomplex(new Apfloat(BigDecimal))` should do the trick.

Comment: new BigDecimal(String.format("%s", ApfloatMath.pow(new Apfloat(v, 10), new Apfloat(p, 10))));

Comment: not works correct `new BigDecimal(String.format("%s", ApfloatMath.pow(new Apfloat(new BigDecimal("2.0"), 16), new Apfloat(new BigDecimal("3.0"), 16))));` return `8.000000000000001` not 8

Comment: @tstorms Why use ApcomplexMath for real exponentiation? Check out ApfloatMath https://github.com/mtommila/apfloat/blob/0c583db22751d56eef9ec0bf40f724f2f4374603/apfloat/src/main/java/org/apfloat/ApfloatMath.java#L1483