# Rounding error in java

Tags: java, double, bigdecimal

I have a Java function that's supposed to calculate dividend interest and Java keeps getting the output off by several digits. I'm having issue finding where the rounding error keeps coming up, so I made a crude copy of my function that breaks the calculation down line by line.

```
public static double applyDivInterest2(double balance, double totalRate, double gRate, double days)
{
    DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.##");
    double result;

    /*Access version of code (can be ignored)
     *dblInterest = prmBalance * ((1 + prmTotalIntRate) ^ dblExponent1 - (1 + prmGuarIntRate) ^ dblExponent1) * _
                                 ((1 + prmRolloverTotalIntRate) ^ dblExponentn - (1 + prmGuarIntRate) ^ dblExponentn) / _
                                 ((1 + prmRolloverTotalIntRate) ^ dblExponent1 - (1 + prmGuarIntRate) ^ dblExponent1)

                    balance * (1+totalRate^(1/365) - 1+gRate^(1/365))*
                              (1+(totalRate-gRate)^days/365 - 1+gRate^days/365)/
                              (1+(totalRate-gRate)^1/365 - 1+gRate^1/365)/

                    balance * (calcTotal - guaranteeTotal) *
                              (rolloverTotal - guaranteeTotalDays)/
                              (rolloverTotalDay - guaranteeTotal)
     */
    double day = 1.00/365.00;
    double dayn = (days-1.00)/365.00;
    double newDays = days/365.00;
    double rollover = totalRate-gRate;
    double newtotal = 1.0 + totalRate;
    double newguarantee = 1.0 + gRate;
    double newrollover = 1.0+rollover;

    double calcTotal = (Math.pow(newtotal,day));
    double guaranteeTotal = (Math.pow(newguarantee,day));
    double guaranteeTotalDays = (Math.pow(newguarantee,newDays));
    double rolloverTotalDays = (Math.pow(newrollover,newDays));
    double rolloverTotalDay = (Math.pow(newrollover,day));

    if(totalRate == gRate)
        result = balance*(calcTotal - guaranteeTotal)*days*guaranteeTotalDays;
    else
        result = balance*((calcTotal-guaranteeTotal)*(rolloverTotalDays-guaranteeTotalDays))/(1.0000272615520089941-guaranteeTotal);
    return Double.valueOf(df.format(result));
}
```

Test Variables:

```
balance = 1000000000
gRate = 0.03
totalRate = 0.04
days = 14
```

Output: 370889.63
Actual: 371019.16

I would use BigDecimal, but I'm raising double values to the power of double values; BigDecimal, to my knowledge, only raises doubles to an int value. Any ideas on how to make this more precise?

**EDIT**: I have tried switch 365 days to 365.25. There is no improvement. Earlier, I did something considered unethical and changed 1.0 to some random value (0.9999867 or something can't remember) and for this particular test case it worked, but failed on any other input.

**EDIT 2**: I have tried to use the X^(A+B)=X^A*X^B method by putting that as a separate function. I have rewritten my function to include BigDecimal functionality:

```
public static BigDecimal testFunc(BigDecimal base, BigDecimal power)
{
    MathContext mcontext = new MathContext(9,RoundingMode.DOWN); //12 works
    int signOf2 = power.signum();
    // Perform X^(A+B)=X^A*X^B (B = remainder)
    double dn1 = base.doubleValue();
    // Compare the same row of digits according to context
    power = power.multiply(new BigDecimal(signOf2)); // n2 is now positive
    BigDecimal remainderOf2 = power.remainder(BigDecimal.ONE);
    BigDecimal n2IntPart = power.subtract(remainderOf2);
    // Calculate big part of the power using context -
    // bigger range and performance but lower accuracy
    BigDecimal intPow = base.pow(n2IntPart.intValueExact(),mcontext);
    BigDecimal doublePow = new BigDecimal(Math.pow(dn1, remainderOf2.doubleValue()));
    BigDecimal result = intPow.multiply(doublePow);
    return result;
}
public static double applyDivInterest(double balance, double totalRate, double gRate, double in_days)
{
    MathContext mcontext  = new MathContext(15);

    DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.###");
    //MONETARY      
    BigDecimal bd_balance = new BigDecimal(balance, mcontext);
    BigDecimal bd_tRate   = new BigDecimal(totalRate, mcontext);
    BigDecimal bd_gRate   = new BigDecimal(gRate, mcontext);
    BigDecimal bd_r   = bd_tRate.subtract(bd_gRate, mcontext);

    //DAYS
    BigDecimal bd_365     = new BigDecimal(365, mcontext);
    BigDecimal bd_days    = new BigDecimal(in_days, mcontext);
    BigDecimal bd_days_minus    = new BigDecimal(in_days-1, mcontext);

    //FINAL DAYS
    BigDecimal day = BigDecimal.ONE.divide(bd_365, mcontext);   //  1/365
    BigDecimal dayn = bd_days_minus.divide(bd_365, mcontext);   //  (days-1)/365    GUARANTEE == TOTAL ONLY!
    BigDecimal days = bd_days.divide(bd_365, mcontext);     //  days/365

    //FINAL RATES
    BigDecimal bd_total = BigDecimal.ONE.add(bd_tRate, mcontext);
    BigDecimal bd_guarantee = BigDecimal.ONE.add(bd_gRate, mcontext);
    BigDecimal bd_rollover = BigDecimal.ONE.add(bd_r, mcontext);

    BigDecimal calcTotal = testFunc(bd_total,day);
    BigDecimal guaranteeTotal = testFunc(bd_guarantee,day);

    BigDecimal rolloverTotalDays = testFunc(bd_rollover,days);
    BigDecimal guaranteeTotalDays = testFunc(bd_guarantee,days);

    BigDecimal rolloverTotal = testFunc(bd_rollover,day);

    BigDecimal Stage1 = calcTotal.subtract(guaranteeTotal, mcontext);
    BigDecimal Stage2 = rolloverTotalDays.subtract(guaranteeTotalDays, mcontext);
    BigDecimal Stage3 = rolloverTotal.subtract(guaranteeTotal, mcontext);
    BigDecimal Stage4 = Stage1.multiply(Stage2, mcontext);
    BigDecimal Stage5 = Stage4.divide(Stage3, mcontext);
    BigDecimal finalStage = bd_balance.multiply(Stage5);

    return Double.valueOf(df.format(finalStage)).doubleValue();
}
```

It still keeps outputting the same error.

Comment: Where did you get "Actual" value? I wonder if instead of 365.00 that source uses 365.25 or something close. I also wonder what the constant 1.0000272615520089941 could have to do with error.

Comment: I modified the code to make daysPerYear an argument, and tried it with 365.25. That gave 370764.43, which is still a bit less than Actual.

Comment: @DSlomer64
Forgot to give a backstory. I'm actually converting calculations that are done by a VBA app into a Java app. The VBA app is considered correct, so whatever value it spits out (actual) is the one to test for
I also tried the quarter of a day approach.

Comment: also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16441769/javas-bigdecimal-powerbigdecimal-exponent-is-there-a-java-library-that-does

Answer (score 0):

You can try the [Apache Commons Math](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/) library, specifically the [BigFraction](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/javadocs/api-3.2/org/apache/commons/math3/fraction/BigFraction.html) class. I think this will do what you want.

Comment: In the actual code, `day` is 0.00273224043715847 and `newDays` is 0.03825136612021858. How does this idea work for exponents between 0 and 1?

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan You're right, that would not have worked. I've edited my answer after some more searching.