# BigInteger power of a BigDecimal in Java

Tags: java, biginteger, bigdecimal

I tried to get the power of a `double` value where the exponent is very large (Java `BigInteger` can contain it (the exponent), for example: 10^30)

That is, I want to find something like **1.75^(10^30)** or **1.23^(34234534534222)**.if the output is too large modify it by getting the modulus by a prime like 10^9+7.

If I want to find a power of an `Integer` I can use **`BigInteger.modPow()`** method which take `BigInteger` arguments:

```
( BigInteger modPow(BigInteger exponent, BigInteger m) )
```

As far as i can go this is what i got in Java

```
new BigDecimal("1.5").pow(1000); // .pow() can get only integers as a parameter , but i want to pass a big number like a BigInteger
```

I cannot find an equivalent for that (**BigInteger.modPow()**) in java for  **`BigDecimal`** 
, or i'm missing that.

Are there any ways to do that - Calculate a large power of a floating point number (a `Decimal`)?

**Example of input and output :**

Input    :  num   // or 1.5 or any decimal number. can be an integer also.

exponent : exp   // big integer or a Long value

output  : num^exp  // **num to ther power exp**

i.e like calculating **1.23^(34234534534222)**

if the output is too large modify it by getting the modulus by a prime like 10^9+7

Comment: I think you might get an unexpected result -as BigDecimals scale support only 32 bit integers-, but you can still do that on your own with the fast exponentiation (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation_by_squaring).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java's BigDecimal.power(BigDecimal exponent): Is there a Java library that does it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16441769/javas-bigdecimal-powerbigdecimal-exponent-is-there-a-java-library-that-does)

Comment: When exactly is "the output too large"?

Comment: @Marco13 it is when the out put is a number and it is too large. Contains too many digits. by getting the mod we can keep  it to a lower limit. in here as i say output will be no greater that 10^9+7

Comment: This is not the case. When you have a value like `0.14534523462656491590485` and take it modulo an integer number, it *still* is `0.14534523462656491590485`. The number of digits can only be reduced when the number becomes too large, but you won't get rid of the fractional digits with that.

Comment: Combining `double` which loses the least significant digits with modulus, which relies on them simply must be wrong. For example, computing `(double) 1.23 ** (34234534534222) % p` makes no sense, as 1.23 can't be exactly represented as double and you get essentially a random number. If double had one more bit of precision, you'd get a completely unrelated garbage number. ++ I guess, it's for project Euler and then you simply must get rid of using `double`.

Answer (score 1):

There is a [Math.BigDecimal implementation of core mathematical functions](http://www.mpia.de/~mathar/progs/jdocs/org/nevec/rjm/BigDecimalMath.html) which has:

```
static java.math.BigDecimal powRound(java.math.BigDecimal x, java.math.BigInteger n) 
          Raise to an integer power and round.
```

which seems exactly what you need. The fact that there is an external library for it denotes that there is no core implementation of a method like this in `java.Math`.

As a side note I can say that if your input is considerably small in terms of decimal places (thus no irrational) just like 1.5 you can transform it in 15/10 and do

```
(15^BigInteger)/(10^BigInteger)
```

with the `modPow(BigInteger exponent, BigInteger m)` of `BigInteger`. This obviously raises the complexity and the numbers to calculate.

Answer (score 0):

There are several caveats. As Gábor Bakos pointed out, the resulting value would most likely contain too many digits to even be represented as a `BigDecimal`.

Additionally, these number of digits grows quickly, so computing something like 2.0<sup>34234534534222</sup> is completely out of scope in terms of storage (and, as I assume, in terms of required time).

You mentioned that the value may be computed modulo a large prime when it becomes "too large". Although you did not say what exactly this means, this won't necessarily help you here, because using modulo will not truncate the *decimal places*. You'll somehow have to limit the precision in which the computation takes place.

However, the most simple implementation using [exponentiation by squaring](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation_by_squaring) could *roughly* look like this:

```
import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.math.BigInteger;

public class BigDecimalPow {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        BigDecimal b = new BigDecimal(1.5);
        BigInteger e = new BigInteger("325322");
        BigDecimal result = pow(b, e);
        System.out.println("Done "+result.scale());
        System.out.println(result);
    }


    /**
     * Computes d to the power of e
     * @param b The value
     * @param e The exponent
     * @return The power
     */
    private static BigDecimal pow(BigDecimal b, BigInteger e) {
        BigDecimal result = BigDecimal.ONE;
        BigDecimal p = b;
        int skipped = 0;
        while (e.compareTo(BigInteger.ZERO) > 0) {
            if (e.and(BigInteger.ONE).equals(BigInteger.ONE)) {
                if (skipped > 0) {

                    if (skipped > 29) {
                        p = pow(p, BigInteger.ONE.shiftLeft(skipped));
                    } else {
                        p = p.pow(1 << skipped);
                    }
                    skipped = 0;
                }
                result = result.multiply(p);
            }
            skipped++;
            e = e.shiftRight(1);
            System.out.println(e);
        }
        return result;
    }

}
```

Note: The implementation above is *really* simple. There most likely is a solution that is more efficient for some cases, or uses the modulo operation to support "larger" numbers. But you simply can not represent (potentially) 34234534534222 decimal places unless you have 34 terabytes of RAM and a JVM with `long` addressing, so I doubt that there will be a solution that satisfies the requirements that you stated until now - but would upvote+bounty anyone who proved me wrong...

Comment: There is similar question can you help me in this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45768020/finding-the-modulor-of-large-numbers