# Java/Android pow precision/scale like in Windows calculator

Tags: java, android, math, precision, pow

Example in Windows calculator when we do "**3^8.73**" result is "**14630,816172800116064202808828951**", but when we do in Java "**Math.pow(3, 8.73)**" result is "**14630.816172800123**".

How can I do pow in Java with presicion like in Windows calculator (32 numbers after comma)?

I can't use BigDecimal class, because there is only pow(int) - I need pow(double) method.

I can't find any solution on about this problem.
There are maybe better classes than BigDecimal for **Android**, where we can do pow(double)?

Thanks for answers :* .

Comment: Use long and BigInteger as if it was decimal, then convert.

Comment: Related question: [Java's BigDecimal.power(BigDecimal exponent): Is there a Java library that does it?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/16441769)

Comment: Yup, I saw this topic, but it don't help me.

Apfloat library is working only on Java, not on Android.

BigDecimalMath isn't good library. Example for "**BigDecimalMath.pow(new BigDecimal("3"), new BigDecimal("8.73"))**" sum is "**6000**".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

omg...

I speend a few days on this. I have tried many algorithms and none of them don't worked... And then I wrote in my function:

```
pow(new BigDecimal(3), new BigDecimal("8.73")) // <-- this is String in 2 argument (good)
```

NOT:

```
pow(new BigDecimal(3), new BigDecimal(8.73)) // <-- this is double in 2 argument (bad)
```

And now all is working...

So if you wanna too have good function/method **pow(BigDecimal x, BigDecimal y)** you must download this class: [BigFunctions.java](https://www.dropbox.com/s/wvwpnczwyu5a5ly/BigFunctions.java?dl=0) (I get this code from this book: [Java Number Cruncher: The Java ...](http://www.apropos-logic.com/nc/index.html)) there is good method **ln**, and **exp** - we need them to our **pow**. Next put this class into your Project and at the end you must write this method in your some class (*complete version of this method is at the end of this post*):

```
public static BigDecimal pow(BigDecimal x, BigDecimal y)
{
    BigDecimal val = BigFunctions.ln(x, 33).setScale(32, RoundingMode.HALF_UP).multiply(y);
    BigDecimal result = BigFunctions.exp(val, 33).setScale(32, RoundingMode.HALF_UP);
    return result;
}
```

---

In some cases like here:

```
BigDecimal x = pow(new BigDecimal(2), new BigDecimal("0.5")); // sqrt(2)
BigDecimal z = pow(x, new BigDecimal(2)); // x^2;
System.out.println(x);
System.out.println(z);
```

We have result:

> 1.41421356237309504880168872420970
>
> 2.00000000000000000000000000000001

So we can modify our method like that:

```
public static BigDecimal pow(BigDecimal x, BigDecimal y)
{
    BigDecimal val = BigFunctions.ln(x, 33).setScale(32, RoundingMode.HALF_UP).multiply(y);
    BigDecimal result = BigFunctions.exp(val, 33).setScale(32, RoundingMode.HALF_UP);
    
    String regExp = "0{30}", resultString = result.toPlainString();
    int commaIndex = resultString.indexOf(".");
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regExp);
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(resultString.substring(commaIndex));
    boolean hasMatch = matcher.find();
    if(hasMatch == true)
    {
        return new BigDecimal(resultString.substring(0, commaIndex));
    }
    return result;
}
```

---

And result is:

> 1.41421356237309504880168872420970
>
> 2

---

---

---

## Edit:

I found one problem - when we enhances big value then his precision isn't good, so below you have final version of pow method.

**COMPLETE POW METHOD:**

```
public static BigDecimal pow(BigDecimal x, BigDecimal y)
{
    String yString = y.toPlainString();
    if(y.compareTo(BigDecimal.valueOf(999999999)) == 1) // In smaller ^values (like 1000000) in each algorithm we must waiting infinitely long so this is only 'protection' from exceptions.
    {
        System.out.println("Too big value for exponentiation");
        return new BigDecimal("0");
    }
    else if(x.compareTo(BigDecimal.valueOf(0)) == 0)
    {
        return new BigDecimal("0");
    }
    int yStringCommaIndex = yString.indexOf(".");

    if(yStringCommaIndex == -1)
    {
        String xString = x.toPlainString(), xString2;
        int precision = xString.indexOf(".")+1;
        if(precision == 0)
        {
            if(xString.length() > 53)
            {
                System.out.println("Too long value of integer number. Max is 53.");
                return new BigDecimal("0");
            }
            precision = xString.length()+1;
        }
        else if(precision > 54)
        {
            System.out.println("Too long value of integer number. Max is 53.");
            return new BigDecimal("0");
        }
        
        BigDecimal result = x.pow(Integer.parseInt(yString)).setScale(32, RoundingMode.HALF_UP);
        xString2 = result.toPlainString();
        precision = xString2.indexOf(".");
        if(precision > 32)
        {
            precision = 32;
        }
        else if(precision == -1 || precision == 1 && xString2.charAt(0) == '0')
        {
            precision = 0;
        }
        result = result.setScale(32-precision, RoundingMode.HALF_UP);
        
        
        String regExp = "9{16}", resultString = result.toPlainString();
        int commaIndex = resultString.indexOf(".");
        if(commaIndex == -1)
        {
            return result;
        }
        String result2 = resultString.substring(0, commaIndex);
        resultString = resultString.substring(commaIndex+1);
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regExp);
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(resultString);
        boolean hasMatch = matcher.find();
        if(hasMatch == true)
        {
            result2 += "."+resultString.substring(0, matcher.start());
            if(result2.endsWith("."))
            {
                result2 = result2.substring(0, commaIndex);
                return new BigDecimal(result2).add(BigDecimal.valueOf(1));
            }
            result2 += "9";
            return new BigDecimal(result2).setScale((result2.length()-1)-(commaIndex+1), RoundingMode.HALF_UP);
        }
        
        regExp = "0{16}|0+$";
        resultString = result.toPlainString();
        commaIndex = resultString.indexOf(".");
        if(commaIndex == -1)
        {
            return result;
        }
        result2 = resultString.substring(0, commaIndex+1);
        resultString = resultString.substring(commaIndex+1);
        pattern = Pattern.compile(regExp);
        matcher = pattern.matcher(resultString);
        hasMatch = matcher.find();
        if(hasMatch == true)
        {
            result2 += resultString.substring(0, matcher.start());
            if(result2.endsWith("."))
            {
                result2 = result2.substring(0, commaIndex);
            }
            return new BigDecimal(result2);
        }
        return result;
    }
    else
    {
        if(x.compareTo(BigDecimal.valueOf(0)) == -1)
        {
            System.out.println("Wrong input values");
            return new BigDecimal("0");
        }
        
        BigDecimal x1 = x.pow(Integer.parseInt(yString.substring(0, yStringCommaIndex))); // Integer value
        
        String xString = x.toPlainString(), xString2;
        int precision = xString.indexOf(".")+1;
        if(precision == 0)
        {
            if(xString.length() > 53)
            {
                System.out.println("Too long value of integer number. Max is 53.");
                return new BigDecimal("0");
            }
            precision = xString.length()+1;
        }
        else if(precision > 54)
        {
            System.out.println("Too long value of integer number. Max is 53.");
            return new BigDecimal("0");
        }
        BigDecimal val = BigFunctions.ln(x, 33).setScale(32, RoundingMode.HALF_UP).multiply(new BigDecimal("0"+yString.substring(yStringCommaIndex)));
        BigDecimal x2 = BigFunctions.exp(val, 33).setScale(32, RoundingMode.HALF_UP); // Decimal value

        BigDecimal result = x1.multiply(x2).setScale(32, RoundingMode.HALF_UP);
        
        xString2 = result.toPlainString();
        precision = xString2.indexOf(".");
        if(precision > 32)
        {
            precision = 32;
        }
        else if(precision == -1 || precision == 1 && xString2.charAt(0) == '0')
        {
            precision = 0;
        }
        result = result.setScale(32-precision, RoundingMode.HALF_UP);
        
        String regExp = "9{16}", resultString = result.toPlainString();
        int commaIndex = resultString.indexOf(".");
        if(commaIndex == -1)
        {
            return result;
        }
        String result2 = resultString.substring(0, commaIndex);
        resultString = resultString.substring(commaIndex+1);
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regExp);
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(resultString);
        boolean hasMatch = matcher.find();
        if(hasMatch == true)
        {
            result2 += "."+resultString.substring(0, matcher.start());
            if(result2.endsWith("."))
            {
                result2 = result2.substring(0, commaIndex);
                return new BigDecimal(result2).add(BigDecimal.valueOf(1));
            }
            result2 += "9";
            return new BigDecimal(result2).setScale((result2.length()-1)-(commaIndex+1), RoundingMode.HALF_UP);
        }
        
        regExp = "0{16}|0+$";
        resultString = result.toPlainString();
        commaIndex = resultString.indexOf(".");
        if(commaIndex == -1)
        {
            return result;
        }
        result2 = resultString.substring(0, commaIndex+1);
        resultString = resultString.substring(commaIndex+1);
        pattern = Pattern.compile(regExp);
        matcher = pattern.matcher(resultString);
        hasMatch = matcher.find();
        if(hasMatch == true)
        {
            result2 += resultString.substring(0, matcher.start());
            if(result2.endsWith("."))
            {
                result2 = result2.substring(0, commaIndex);
            }
            return new BigDecimal(result2);
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```