# Java how to compute BigDecimal to the power of BigDecimal (both possibly negative)

Tags: java, bigdecimal

Given in input two BigDecimal, one for the base and one for the exponent:

```
BigDecimal base;
BigDecimal exponent;
```

Considering that they can have both **positive** and **negative** signums, how can I calculate the power `base^exponent` ?

I found the following method in the `BigDecimal class`, but it accepts only `int` as the exponent.

```
public BigDecimal pow(int n);
```

Then after an extra search I found https://github.com/aaiyer/SuanShu/blob/master/src/main/java/com/numericalmethod/suanshu/number/big/BigDecimalUtils.java#LC147

exploiting the equality `z = x^y --> z = exp ( ln(x) * y )`

but how can I calculate it in the case of negative base and exponents?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java's BigDecimal.power(BigDecimal exponent): Is there a Java library that does it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16441769/javas-bigdecimal-powerbigdecimal-exponent-is-there-a-java-library-that-does)

Comment: Use `x^(-y) == 1/(x^y)`. For `-x` you'd better ensure `y` is an integer.