# Java pow without rounding up the final value

Tags: java, math, formula

I am trying to write a formula for one of my functions where I need to raise my X to power of Y. The values I am working with are really small and will get rounded up as soon as I use pow function of Math, BigInteger and BigDecimal.

For example if I use the following values it will return **1000** whereas it should return **1006.931669**!
T0 = 1000, TN = 1, k = 1, N = 1000

[image: Formula]

```
    double X = (finalTemp/initialTemp);
    double A = Math.pow(X, (k/n));
    double tk = initialTemp * A;
```

Comment: Please show the code you're using

Comment: @Lino Code added!

Comment: I guess you have that problem because of how [Integer division works in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4685450/int-division-why-is-the-result-of-1-3-0). To fix your problem, you probably need *Floating point division*

Comment: first multiply all terms in the numerator then divide by denominator

Comment: Maybe this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16441769/javas-bigdecimal-powerbigdecimal-exponent-is-there-a-java-library-that-does

Comment: Did you try the type to float ?

Comment: `pow` never rounds its return value. Your problem is due to integer rounding in either `finalTemp/initialTemp` or `k/n`. You probably stumbled across a specific case in which integer division gave the same results as floating point division.

Comment: Duplicate of [Integer division: How do you produce a double?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3144610/integer-division-how-do-you-produce-a-double)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They are being divided in integer arithmetics. So dividing integer a by integer b you get how many times b fits into a, If the types of the operands are double, then "real" division is performed.

```
double X = (finalTemp/(double)initialTemp);
double A = Math.pow(X, (k/(double)n));
double tk = initialTemp * A;
```

Comment: Shouldn't you also cast `n` to `double`?

Comment: yes, you need to cast.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation, it makes total sense now!

Answer (score 2):

the output is correct according to calculator

```
public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        double finalTemp = 1.0;
        double initialTemp = 1000.0;
        double k = 1.0;
        double n = 1000.0;
        double X = (finalTemp/initialTemp);
        double A = Math.pow(X, (k/n));
        double tk = initialTemp * A;
        System.out.println(tk);
    }
}
```

output is `993.1160484209338`