# BigDecimal for monthly interest rate

Tags: java, bigdecimal

It is often said (e.g. by Josh Bloch in "Effective Java") that we shouldn't use floating-point types, such as `double`, for financial calculations. How, then, can we calculate a monthly interest rate given an annual rate?

The formula is:

```
monthly rate = (1 + annual rate)^(1/12) - 1
```

But BigDecimal doesn't have a `pow(BigDecimal)` method, nor an `nthRoot(int) method. So we can't call`rate.pow(1.0/12)`nor`rate.nthroot(12)` because those methods don't exist. If we do this:

```
monthlyRate = BigDecimal.valueOf(Math.pow(1 + rate.doubleValue(), 1.0/12) - 1)
```

then it defeats the purpose of using `BigDecimal` in order to avoid using `double`.

Comment: I thought they had BigDecimal.pow(int n)

Comment: @LoganWlv whilst `1/12` is technically an `int`, I suspect OP really means `1.0 / 12.0`.

Comment: @LoganWlv very right, there is this `pow(int n)`, which cannot compute to the power of `1.1`.

Comment: Maybe you'll find here some answers as well: https://stackoverflow.com/q/16441769/582675