# Expressions with BigDecimal Java / Kotlin

Tags: java, kotlin, bigdecimal

I need help from those who understand Java / Kotlin.

I would like to perform some calculations with BigDecimal

How would the expression below look using BigDecimal?

**(1 + 0.02) ^ (1 / 251) - 1**

I tried to do like this:

```
val x = (BigDecimal.ONE + BigDecimal(0.02)).pow(1/251) - 1
```

However, dividing 1 by 251 is not accurate and this expression always returns 0

Comment: Are you using Java, or Kotlin?  It makes a difference.  You'll need to pick one to get an accurate answer.

Comment: You can't actually do this equation using entirely `BigDecimal` numbers because Java's BigDecimal has no `pow` function (or any exponentiation operation by whatever name) that takes a `BigDecimal` argument. `BigDecimal` is not designed for scientific calculations like this one; its main use is for financial/accounting and similar domains.

Comment: To use a fractional exponent, find a third-party library. See related Questions: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3579779/642706), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11848887/642706), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16441769/642706).

Answer (score 3):

*dividing 1 by 251 is not accurate and this expression always returns 0*

This would result in Integer division,  To cure integer division you can do `1.00/251`.

Also you are missing a `new` before `BigDecimal(0.02)`, but even if you did there there is no operator `+` for `BigDecimal` and the `plus` method should be used.

Comment: In Kotlin, the [BigDecimal.plus](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/java.math.-big-decimal/plus.html) function is an operator function which [overloads](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/operator-overloading.html#binary-operations) `+`. Kotlin also does away with the `new` keyword.

Comment: @slaw, thanks I did not notice the Kotlin tag