# Is it possible to limit two decimal places with Float type without type conversion in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin

Is it possible to limit two decimal places with Float type without type conversion in Kotlin?
I hope it rounded(but not necessary)
for example, I want a value of float type 1100.34610 -> 1100.35 (or 1100.34 is still fine) but should keep the type as float. I don't want it to be Double or String while limiting decimal places.

Most of the posts did type conversion to Double or String while limiting decimal places. But I don't want that. No type conversion should happen while limiting decimal places.

Comment: You can't do that (nor can you with a double). If you want that, you should use `BigDecimal`.

Comment: What is your _actual_ requirement? Why do you want to limit to 2 dp? Is it just for display purposes, or do you want to limit to 2 dp for all intermediate calculations?

Comment: Floats do not store decimal places.  They store binary places.  There is no float (or double) value that's exactly 1100.34610 in decimal — the code simply stores the nearest value, and then rounds it when formatting to decimal for display.  If you need exact decimal places, then floats (and doubles) are not a suitable type.  It's usually much better to store as BigDecimal, and then format that to string as needed for display purposes.  See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/588004/10134209) for more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you reject any data type conversion the answer is "No". There's no configurable precision in `Float` and you cannot do it with `Double` either. Converting to `String` is not really a solution either - it's just matter of value representation and doing further math on strings ain't effective. It sounds like you are tryting to solve the problem you created yourself.

BTW: if you decide to go for `BigDecimal` be aware of [some quirks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65929370/expressions-with-bigdecimal-java-kotlin).