# Take Power of Decimal to Maximum Precision

Tags: java, math, bigdecimal

I want to do the following in java:

Math.pow((int),(double))

and keep the decimal precision to more than 16 (much greater than that actually).

Is this possible? I know it involves using BigDecimal and maybe ln functions, but I'm not sure how to approach this.

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT**

The reason I am asking is because I am trying to compute pi to an enormous amount of precision. Currently, I am using Chudnovsky's algorithm. I've tried to use taylor series for this purpose and it takes much too long to be practical.

EDIT

Maybe this is a better question: How do you find the square root of a BigDecimal. (Technically, same as the original since raising to the .5 is...)

Comment: You need to find an approximation formula (e.g. Taylor series), and compute it with BigDecimal.

Comment: Check this out (by Mysticial): http://www.numberworld.org/y-cruncher/algorithms.html

Comment: @Kgrover If you wanna raise it to a *decimal* power, you might as well start by implementing *exp()* and *log()*. Since a fully generic `a^b` is usually implemented as `e^(b log(a))`. In any case, computing Pi doesn't require a decimal power.

Comment: I am using the Chudnovsky's algorithm: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Approximations_of_%CF%80#20th_century

I see that it does need to be raised to the 3/2 power. Is there a faster/easier way to approximate (er- with a lot of precision) pi?

Comment: For square roots, you should use Newton's Method.

Comment: Look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3579779/how-to-do-a-fractional-power-on-bigdecimal-in-java) question.