# Arbitrary precision exponentiation in Clojure

Tags: math, clojure

Is there way to perform arbitrary precision exponentiation in Clojure? I've tried Math/pow and the expt function from clojure.math.numeric-tower, but both will only return limited precision. For example:

```
(with-precision 100 (expt 2 1/2))
=> 1.4142135623730951
```

How do I get more digits?

Comment: How many digits do you want? `sqrt(2)` can't be expressed as a rational number (as a fraction of two finite numbers). Do you want a lazy list of digits?

Comment: I tried to get 100 digits by using "with-precision", but as you can see that did nothing. The answer is: I want to specify the precision. The expt function accepts bigdec arguments but only returns limited precision results.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Apfloat for Java](http://www.apfloat.org/apfloat_java/) provides fast arbitrary precision arithmetic. You can easily use it by adding the following dependency information to your `project.clj` file, if your project comes with Leiningen.

```
[org.apfloat/apfloat "1.6.3"]
```

You can perform arbitrary precision exponentiation in Clojure using Apfloat. For example:

```
user> (import '(org.apfloat Apfloat ApfloatMath))
org.apfloat.ApfloatMath

user> (-> (Apfloat. 2M 100) (ApfloatMath/pow (Apfloat. 0.5M 100)))
1.4142135623730950488016887242096980785696718753769480731766797379907324784621070388503875343276415727
```

Answer (score 2):

`math/expt` is likely not the function you are looking for as it returns a double instead of a BigDecimal in this context, and hence ignores your `with-precision` statement:

> Returns an exact number if the base is an exact number and the power is an integer, otherwise returns a double.

```
user> (type (with-precision 100 (math/expt 2M 1/2)))
java.lang.Double
```

the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3579779/how-to-do-a-fractional-power-on-bigdecimal-in-java) seems to cover how to get arbitrary precision out of BigDecimal exponentiation. BigDecimal seems not to provide this "out of the box"

Comment: In that case, what *is* the function that the OP is looking for?