# How to bring BigDecimal to fractional power?

Tags: java

BigDecimal was the choice to store numbers that have up to 5 digits after decimal point. I need to raise the BigDecimal to fractional power (up to 2 digits after decimal point). 
For example I have to bring 9.09671 to power of 1.51. Do I need some conversions from/to BigDecimal? How to do it?

**EDIT:**
I cannot use 3rd party libraries as described in [Java's BigDecimal.power(BigDecimal exponent): Is there a Java library that does it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16441769/javas-bigdecimal-powerbigdecimal-exponent-is-there-a-java-library-that-does)

Is there more elegant, succint way for this case than described in [How to do a fractional power on BigDecimal in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3579779/how-to-do-a-fractional-power-on-bigdecimal-in-java)

Comment: Could you explain why BigDecimal was chosen to represent the numbers? It may be, this choice was not optimal if operations like powering with a fraction are necessary.

Comment: I need to get precise result while doing subtraction, multiplication and bringing to power numbers that have up to 5 digits after decimal point. I cannot use any external libraries except provided with Java SE 5 .

Comment: Precise in what sense? Multiplying two numbers with 5 decimal places will in general have a result with 10 decimal places.

Comment: @Henry, Would You suggest to use `double` for this particular case?

Comment: Yes, unless your numbers have more than about 15 digits in total.