# Java See if a number can be square/cube rooted

Tags: java

I would like to square/cube root but also 4,5,etc. how would I do this?
I can do square

```
public static boolean isSquareNumber(int n) {
    int a  = (int) Math.sqrt(n);
    if(Math.pow(a, 2) == n) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

How would I do this for other powers?

Comment: The `n`th root of `x` can be given by `Math.pow(x, 1.0/n)`.

Comment: It's a math problem, not a java one, vote to close, not the appropriate place

Comment: This is more of a math question than java. You can do Math.pow(a, 1.0/p) where p is the power you want and of type double, e.g. 2, 3, ...etc

Comment: @azro That may be true, but I wanted to create a java program to solve them, so I thought it went in java.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Calculating nth root in Java using power method](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32553108/calculating-nth-root-in-java-using-power-method)

Comment: Very useful link, @Akceptor, certainly relevant. I don’t think this is an exact duplicate, though.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you take the power and find the inverse of it, `1/power` it gives you the root of that power.

```
public static boolean isPowerNumber(int n, double power) {
    int a = (int) Math.pow(n, (1/power));
    if(Math.pow(a,power) == n) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Here is the code that you will need.

Comment: `1/power` will give you zero for any int `power` > 1.

Comment: change "power" from int to double

Answer (score 1):

The hole issue is about how you are addressing the problem(IMHO)

a number **x** can be rooted to a base **n** if:

the **x^(1/n)** is an integer, **where n > 0**

therefore the approach could be:

```
public static void main(final String[] args) {
    for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
        System.out.println(" has " + i + " exactly a root base2(square)? " + isRootInteger(i, 2));
        System.out.println(" has " + i + " exactly a root base3(cubic)? " + isRootInteger(i, 3));
    }

}

public static boolean isRootInteger(int number, int root) {
    double dResult = Math.pow(number, 1.0 / root);

    if ((dResult == Math.floor(dResult)) && !Double.isInfinite(dResult)) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```