# Approximate logarithm of BigInteger

Tags: java, biginteger, logarithm, fixed-point

I am looking for a fast way to approximate the logarithm base 2 of a `BigInteger`. Speed and support for large numbers are more important than exact results. My current suggestion is:

`return BigInteger.valueOf(n.bitLength());`

I highly assume that this gives a correct approximation for numbers up to 2^(2^31-1). But can it be done faster? I am not sure how efficient `bitLength()` is?

All comments and suggestions are highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

**Update:** This is not a duplicate, because I was looking for the fastest way to perform the operation where accuracy is not that much of an issue. In the end, I decided to use `double` approximations.

Comment: How Accurate does it have to be? IMHO getting the bit length is really inaccurate. Also, how big do you think your numbers will be?

Comment: Possible [duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6827516/230513).

Comment: @CarlosBribiescas: The numbers will be 80 to 100 bit integers. If there are more accurate and possibly faster ways, I'd be more than happy to get to know them. Thanks.