# Number of digits in an integral number (large size)

Tags: java

I have a collection of [`BigInteger`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html)s and am trying to get the number of digits in each integral number. For the sake of brevity, lets say that we are only dealing with *positive* numbers. We are looking at numbers with over 1000 digits.

The following are the ways I have thought of.

1. length of a string representation (will require a bunch of memory)
2. modulo 10 approach (slow)
3. an asanine idea (included for sake of thoroughness, since scalability of this approach is not great)

   ```
   if (i >= 100000000) {
       i /= 100000000;
       n += 8;
   }
   if (i >= 10000) {
       i /= 10000;
       n += 4;
   }
   if (i >= 100) {
       i /= 100;
       n += 2;
   }
   if (i >= 10) {
       i /= 10;
       n += 1;
   }
   ```
4. logarithms (which I find rather friendly) (credits go to [[this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7982137/1692706)])

   ```
   int blex = val.bitLength() - 1022; // any value in 60..1023 is ok
   if (blex > 0)
       val = val.shiftRight(blex);
   double res = Math.log10(val.doubleValue());
   return blex > 0 ? res + blex * LOG2 : res;
   ```
5. This is an idea I have but want to test the validity of before coding; say I have some number `x`. Try to divide by powers of 10 using concepts of (traditional or one-sided) binary search, and stop when `0 < quotient < 10`. That `power + 1` should be the number of digits. This would be a logarithmic solution (?).

StackOverflow did not really seem to have something solid to calculate the number of digits in **any number**. This [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18860385/1692706) suggests a division-heavy approach that can result in a bunch of new objects being created. I was wondering if there can be a slicker solution. So, I thought this post would lead to a fruitful discussion and collaboration of ideas. Please suggest which method would work best for really large numbers.

Comment: have you looked at http://stackoverflow.com/a/23773083/5808727 ?

Comment: @Pooya Yep! The `bitLength()` function being used there; I am not entirely sure of how that would play out in terms of performance; more so, in terms of accuracy (see Dariusz's answer). I might be very wrong though. Hence this post. :)

Comment: I think it worth benchmarking couple of these answers on the same system

Comment: I'll do benchmarks on all of these and post it as an answer soon

Comment: each 10-bit limb corresponds to about 3 decimal digits, so you can count the number of bits (of the full limb) and multiply it 3/10 then add the number of digits in the last limb

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc That is an interesting approach. Wouldn't that result in some loss of accuracy?

Comment: Yes the actual value might be a little smaller so it needs some correction. How to calculate that correction is out of my ability, maybe some mathematician can help. I've seen a function to convert floating-point to string uses this way to get the number of digits

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc I see. Thanks for the note. I will look into it and update.

Comment: this may help http://www.exploringbinary.com/how-the-positive-powers-of-ten-and-two-are-interleaved/