# How to find the log of a number?

Tags: c++, math, logarithm, bignum

I have a number (num1) which is 18 digits long. I am storing it in an integer array.
I have another number (num2) which is also 18 digits long. This is also being stored in an integer array.

I have to find the log of the first number to the base of the second number (log num1 to base num2).

How to do this in C++? I can't use the log function as the numbers are being stored in arrays.

Comment: Do you have a big numbers library you're using? If not - get one.

Comment: If you want to do it manually, see the answer to this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/739532/logarithm-of-a-bigdecimal

Comment: 18 digits of what?  Stored in these integers how?  What endianness?  Packed binary? ASCII hex?  ASCII decimal?  What?  In what form do you want the output?

Comment: Show us what you have so far, especially how the numbers are stored. And the result, must it be exact or can it be an approximation (with, say, 53 bits of precision)?

Comment: This sounds like a very confused and incomplete question on the [discrete log problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_log).

Comment: the result is 42.7782414582334

Answer (score 2):

They key term to google for is `bigint`. There are various C++ libraries which support `bigints` (that is, number which can be as long as your memory permits).

The only bigint library I've used myself is [GMP](http://gmplib.org/). However, if you just need a single function on bigints (log, in your case), then maybe taking some smaller library (is more practical).

Just checked the GMP page and incidentally, it calls them `bignums` all over. So that may be another useful term to use when searching for a solution. ;-)