# How to avoid overflow with large logarithms

Tags: java, overflow, logarithm

I'm trying to compute a large logarithim in Java and cannot work out how to work around the overflow problem.  Research says I need to use the BigDecimal class, but I cannot cast a double into this.
Can anyone help?

Cheers, here's an example of what I'm trying to compute:
Math.log10(13168375/4224127912)

Comment: I'm not sure what the issue is here.  Why can't you just do `log10(13168375) - log10(4224127912)`?  Where is the overflow?

Comment: Why can't you just create a new `BigDecimal` from the `double` instead of casting? `BigDecimal someNumber = new BigDecimal(doublVal);`

Comment: If you want to calculate the `log` of a BigDecimal, see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/745987/391161).

Answer (score 1):

You have to interpret the error messages.

```
Y.java:16: error: integer number too large: 4224127912
        System.out.println(          Math.log10(13168375/4224127912) );
                                                     ^
```

This means that 4224127912 (!) is too big for an integer.

You may:

```
 Math.log10(13168375/4224127912.0)   // use a double literal

 Math.log10((double)13168375/4224127912L)    // use a long literal  
 Math.log10(13168375.0/4224127912L)          // use a long literal
```

No `overflow`!

And no logarithm around here is "large".

Comment: @GriffeyDog Hey,thanks - I was concentrating on avoiding the error message. I had a ".0" added to the first number as well.