# Bigdecimal logarithm in Java

Tags: java, bigdecimal, logarithm

I want to calculate the logarithm of the `transmitter.getETXPOW()`, what is `BigDecimal` format.

```
BigDecimal power =  transmitter.getETXPOW();
BigDecimal eirp = 10 * Math.log(power);
```

I received an error message, `BigDecimal` can not be converted to `double`.

Logarithm base is 10.

Comment: what is transmitter.getETXPOW?

Comment: You're passing `power` to the `Math.log()` method, which takes a `double`, not a `BigDecimal`.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/739532/logarithm-of-a-bigdecimal?rq=1

Comment: For completeness - `Math.log` is the natural log.  `Math.log10` is what you want to use if you want a base-10 log.  You could always do a change-of-base operation if you really needed to, as well.

Answer (score 1):

To convert to double value use `BigDecimal` class `doubleValue()`. See demo

```
import java.math.*;

public class BigDecimalDemo {

   public static void main(String[] args) {

      // create a BigDecimal object
      BigDecimal bg;

      // create a Double object
      Double d;

      bg=new BigDecimal("1234");

      // assign the converted value of bg to d
      d=bg.doubleValue();

      String str = "Double value of " + bg + " is " + d;

      // print d value
      System.out.println( str );
   }
}
```