# How to calculate log16 of a 256 bit Integer in Golang

Tags: go, math

how to get the log with base 16 for a math/big Int variable.

Any help would be great since I am new to Go and came from Python and C environment

```
s := "c6d86e5a2cb4bc532361c2d4940f0b1a0138066e25d65c1c530d080b11f8ca24" // Hex value
i := new(big.Int)
i.SetString(s, 16) // hex value to Big Int
// how to get the log with base 16 for a math/big Int variable.
```

How it works in python

```
import math 
a = 0xc6d86e5a2cb4bc532361c2d4940f0b1a0138066e25d65c1c530d080b11f8ca24
a>> 89940344608680314083397671686667731393131665861770496634981932531495305005604L
math.log(a)/math.log(16.0)
```

answer turns out to be 63.908875905794794

Answer (score 6):

An interesting property of logarithms is that change-of-base is actually pretty easy.

```
log_b (x) = log_a (x) / log_a (b)
```

So if you want to get `log_16 (x)`, you could use the [Log](https://golang.org/src/math/log.go?s=2809:2836#L70) function and do change of base:

```
log_e (x) = log_16 (x) / log_16 (e)
log_16 (e) = approximately 0.36067 
=> log_16 (x) = 0.36067 * log_e (x)
```

So in Go, I think this would be:

```
li := Log(i) * 0.36067
```

Edit: When I wrote the answer above I did not realize that `Log` wouldn't work on a Big Int.  Reading the [Go Github](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/14102), it looks like this is a requested feature in the language which has not yet been implemented due to lack of a satisfactorily quick solution.  From what I read it looks like the best solution for the moment, if you must use a Big Int, is probably a Taylor Series implementation, which in my opinion would be non-trivial to write.  The thread I linked to indicates that one or more such implementations may exist but are not necessarily computationally correct.

Comment: log function accepts float64 type parameters but I have a big Int

Comment: @MohitGupta gotcha!  Then my answer is insufficient.  I'll take a look this afternoon; hopefully someone else will figure it out before then.

Answer (score 5):

There is specific approach for log16 and hex input without long arithmetics.

To get integer (floored) result, just count hex digits. In this case there are 63 digits, so you have

```
  FloorLog16 = 63
```

Now get 8 first digits  (more to enhance precision)

```
  b = 0xc6d86e5a
```

and get log16

```
 p = log(b) / log(16) = 7.908875905775919
```

Use fractional part of this result to make logarithm more exact

```
fp = p - Floor(p) = 0.908875905775919
log16(0xc6d86e5a2cb4bc532361c2d4940f0b1a0138066e25d65c1c530d080b11f8ca24) = 
      63 + 0.908875905775919 = 63.908875905775919
```

Note 12 exact digits

Answer (score 1):

First you need to convert the hex string to the correct hex notation by adding "0x" at the beginning. Next write a `log16` method, use `strconv` to get the integer, than `float64` for the input of the `log` method. **Caution: this solution does not deal with integer overflow.**

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "math"
    "strconv"
)

func log16(x float64) float64 {
    return math.Log(x)/math.Log(16.0)   
}

func main() {
    s := "c6d86e5a2cb4bc532361c2d4940f0b1a0138066e25d65c1c530d080b11f8ca24"
    s1 := "0x" + s
    h, _ := strconv.ParseInt(s1,0,64)
    fmt.Println(log16(float64(h)))

}
```

Comment: The bits overflow float64, the number is really big for it. Check my edit for the question.

Comment: answer turns out to be 15.75 but should be 63.908875905794794

Comment: Sorry, did not think about that. I'm not aware of any existing implementation. There is the package`math/big/decimal` and an implementation to solve the natural logarithm in java in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/739532/logarithm-of-a-bigdecimal, maybe you can go from there.