# Getting logarithm value of a big Integer

Tags: java, biginteger, logarithm

I am trying to find the logarithmic value for a<sup>x</sup> where a <= 9999 and x <= 9999, e.g. 99<sup>99</sup> I got as 656.3063053878814, i.e. I got only 13 digits after the decimal point. I would like to know if I can get at least 50 to 99 digits after the decimal point.
Thanks in advance.

I copied the code from one of the member from this group written in Java and used it. No idea if it's OK to paste here, hence asking for a simpler code in Java, please.

Comment: `System.out.println(java.math.BigInteger.valueOf(99).pow(99));`

Comment: If that code comes from Stack Overflow, it’s perfectly OK to post it here. You may additionally link to the post you took it from for credit.

Comment: Convert to a `BigDecimal` using `new BigDecimal(BigInteger.valueOf(99).pow(99))` and then apply [Logarithm of a BigDecimal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/739532/logarithm-of-a-bigdecimal). There isn’t any method built into Java, so it’s necessarily as manual as that. Don’t know whether that was the post you were referring to.

Comment: The log (a\*\*x) = x \* log(a). Other than that see the comment by @OleV.V.